# Is destructuring input parameters available in Scala?

Tags: scala, clojure

Is there a way to destructure input parameters of a function in Scala ([akin to Clojure](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20%28Destructuring%29))?

So, instead of

```
scala> def f(p: (Int, Int)) = p._1
f: (p: (Int, Int))Int
```

I'd like to have this (it doesn't work):

```
scala> def f((p1, p2): (Int, Int)) = p1
```

Comment: Request for the same in Scala's issue tracker: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7909

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess in scala you would use pattern matching to achieve the same, e.g. like this:

```
val f: (Int, Int) => Int = { case (p1, p2) => p1 }
```

Or, equivalently:

```
def f(p: (Int, Int)) = p match { case(p1, p2) => p1 }
```

If the types can be inferred, the `(Int, Int) => Int` can be dropped:

```
List((1, 2), (3, 4)) map { case (p1, p2) => p1 }
```

Comment: I'd rather avoid using pattern matching as a too verbose solution. I can accept it, though, if there's no other, idiomatic approach. Is there one?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski - This is the best you're going to get.  Tuples and method parameters aren't fully unified, and this is one of the places where you notice.  You can, however, `def f(p1: Int, p2: Int) = p1+p2` and then `(f _).tupled` to create a function that takes a tuple even though the `def` took separate parameters.

Comment: So the short answer is **no**.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(p: ((Int, Int), (Int, Int))) = p._1     > f: (p: ((Int, Int), (Int, Int)))(Int, Int)
f((1,2), (3,4))                               > res1: (Int, Int) = (1,2)
```